# Recorded scripts in jmeter gives 401 Unauthorized error

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

i am trying to load test my application. But when i try to run the recorded scripts through jmeter, i get 401 Unauthorized error only on few particular pages. The script runs while Login page but gives errors on other pages. I need to run this whole scenario using multiple users (CSV file)
this is the Request Tab:

POST data:
{"searchObject":{"LastName":"","FirstName":"","RoleId":"","StatusId":"","sortOrder":"Id","isAsc":"False","isInactivated":false,"tempDataFlag":"True"},"isSorting":"false","listName":"CreissStaffList"}

```
Cookie Data:
ASP.NET_SessionId=0zqlv4t4ayszinlteqgnlrvg; __RequestVerificationToken=mmFzWMMfWojIH9J-32ylhW_8oseKWMP84XRZALQmUh0VfGmflM_kVW3b1MmWYLJ5ySCIezacyBFYplhzTSWMeo7CnMh2j14sD10qX2S_fq41

Request Headers:
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: https://www.creissmed.de/Admin/UserList
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Content-Length: 199
```

Sampler Result:

```
Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start: 2016-02-17 17:17:05 IST
Load time: 142
Connect Time: 0
Latency: 142
Size in bytes: 1599
Headers size in bytes: 255
Body size in bytes: 1344
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Response code: 401
Response message: Unauthorized

Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html
Location: /
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 4.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 17 Feb 2016 11:47:03 GMT
Content-Length: 1344


HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: text/html
DataEncoding: iso-8859-1
```

This is what the HTTP Request Page looks like: 
Path: /Admin/GetListData
BODY PARAMETERS :

```
{"searchObject":{"LastName":"","FirstName":"","RoleId":"","StatusId":"","sortOrder":"Id","isAsc":"False","isInactivated":false,"tempDataFlag":"True"},"isSorting":"false","listName":"CreissStaffList"}
```

I am getting erros only on GetListData HTTP Request Pages
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

1. Add [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener and inspect response details. If you don't see error message it doesn't necessarily mean that login succeeded, despite HTTP Response Code 200 the page may contain errors.
2. You may have to do some handling of the `__RequestVerificationToken` as at is anti-cross-site-forgery implementation and you'll need to do some correlation in order to bypass it. See [How to Load Test CSRF-Protected Web Sites](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-csrf-protected-web-sites) guide for comprehensive explanation and possible options.